# Finding MAX() from a SUM()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, max

I need to get the passenger with the most miles flown.

```
SELECT TP.strFirstName, 
    TP.strLastName, 
    sum(TF.intMilesFlown)
FROM TPassengers AS TP
JOIN TFlightPassengers AS TFP
     ON TP.intPassengerID = TFP.intPassengerID
JOIN TFlights AS TF
     ON TFP.intFlightID = TF.intFlightID          
GROUP BY TP.strLastName, 
    TP.strFirstName
```

So this finds my sum but I don't know how to find the sum's max. I know it probably takes some subquery.

Comment: @charlieface I always forget you can order by aggregations even if you can't group by them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TOP 1` with an `ORDER BY..DESC` to get the max row.

```
SELECT TOP 1 TP.strFirstName, 
    TP.strLastName, 
    sum(TF.intMilesFlown)
FROM TPassengers AS TP
JOIN TFlightPassengers AS TFP
     ON TP.intPassengerID = TFP.intPassengerID
JOIN TFlights AS TF
     ON TFP.intFlightID = TF.intFlightID          
GROUP BY TP.strLastName, 
    TP.strFirstName
ORDER BY SUM(TF.intMilesFlown) DESC;
```